# Alpine not installing "latest" package

Tags: linux, chrome, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I am trying to install latest version of chromium (v108.0.5359.125), and I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.20.1-alpine3.16

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

RUN echo @latest https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo @14.20.1 https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache --update add \
    libsrt@latest \
    chromium@latest \
    firefox@latest
```

I can [clearly see that the Chromium version in the Alpine's repository is indeed v108](https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/aarch64/).

However, for some reason it's installing version 102!

```
(131/133) Installing chromium (102.0.5005.182-r0)
```

`cat /etc/apk/repositories`:

```
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community
@latest https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community
@14.20.1 https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, any pointers is much appreciated!

EDIT: I do not want to specify the version, instead, I'd like to install whatever is latest. (so no `chromium=108.0.5359.125-r0`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Alpine package manager needs the `main` repository listed along with the `community` in order for it to work. I am not sure why, but it works. I'd love to know why if someone can share.

This worked:

```
RUN echo @latest https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo @latest https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo @14.20.1 https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache --update add \
    libsrt@latest \
    chromium@latest \
    firefox@latest
```

Now installs the correct version:

```
(141/161) Installing chromium@latest (108.0.5359.125-r0)
```